# How to display data in React after querying the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to React. I've been using template engines, for a long time. I would even say too long. I'm just getting my feet wet in react.

Let's see the problem:
In many apps that I worked before, I've been using this pattern-fetching something from database, and then rendering the page making the fetched data local to the view. For example:

```
//express powered backend
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //do something with the database and then:
    res.render('some_template_view', {
        fetched_data,
    });
})
```

How do you do that in react? I could fetch something as the component mounts, but I think there's probably some other way?

Comment: Fetching when the component mounts is actually pretty standard in react. Provide some valid initial state and conditionally render some "loading" UI while the data is being fetched. If you can, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for this you can use express as an api for database and use fetch or xhr on client-side.

Look at this example:

```
// index.js - express app
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.get('/database', (req, res) => {
  // Process data from your database
  res.json(/*Info to be sent*/{name: 'Peter'});
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is running'));
```

```
// index.js - React app example
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Example fetch
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/database')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => { return this.setState({name: data.name})})
      .catch(console.log);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>Data received: </h1>
          <p>{this.state.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById(/*Root element id*/'root')
);
```